# Why can't I install MinGW? It shows this problem:

Tags: compiler-errors, mingw, mingw-w64, mingw32

I have a problem installing packages on the MinGW (the old version because I can't sownload the last one at all. It transfers me to the Virus Total page and shows that it has a virus. I have no idea what can that be also) .
It shows this error (shown on the picture)

What can it be?

Tell me, if you need to know which packages I wanted to install

I did everything how it was explained on the tutorial. It seems like I have some problems with my computer because sometimes I have difficulties installing other programms, but I have no idea what...

Answer (score 0):

Use MinGW-w64 instead of the old version. It supports both Windows 32-bit and 64-bit.

You can download a standalone Windows build from https://winlibs.com/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is the Virus Total doesn't allow me to do that. Maybe you know how to disable it? I didn't find the solution

Comment: If you can't even download it, there is a chance you won't be allowed to copy or run it either, even if you get the download from somewhere else (e.g. USB stick).